# Python selenium webdriver gets nothing but the browser normally shows the webpage

Tags: python, selenium, safari, get, webdriver

Source Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Safari()
html_doc = browser.get("http://www.google.com")
#html_doc is empty but the Safari window shows the page normally
#Allow Remote Automation is enabled
```

This is the first time I use Selenium, at first it worked normally, with html_doc normally gets the content, however, the problem occurred several hours later, and neither restart Python nor restart the computer worked. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: browser.get() has no return value. If you want to get page source, you need to use page_source function for it

Comment: html_doc gets what type content as that worked for you. But get() function is for navigation purposes has no return value at all. just curious what you got. So that you can raise a new issue in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`browser.get` doesn't return anything, that's why `html_doc` is empty. If you want the page source you need to use `page_source`

```
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
html_doc = browser.page_source
```